# Does the Conductors of Magic mutagen affect the Supercharged Glyphs ability?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine

Does the Supercharged Glyphs ability, which usually does 10-50 damage per second, get buffed by the Conductors of Magic mutagen?

Supercharged Glyphs:

> Enemies under the influence of Yrden lose 10 points of Vitality or
>   Essence per second.

Conductors of Magic:

> With a magic, unique, or witcher sword in hand, damage dealt by your
>   signs increases by 50% of the equipped sword's own damage.

Their descriptions imply it would work, but I would like to check I'm not spending all my points on a combo that won't actually work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creator of [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/6gadu0/blood_and_wine_mutation_question/) experimented to see how Conductors of Magic affected a few skills, including Supercharged Glyphs. It looks like Conductors of Magic does **not** buff Supercharged Glyphs, unfortunately.

> Did some experimenting, seems that Shockwave and Magic Trap are affected by Conductors of Magic but Supercharged Glyphs isn't, and I can barely tell if there's a difference with Firestream.
>
> Similarly, with Magic Sensibilities, Firestream did crit - but only for 110, and that was with full griffin grandmaster armour in a yrden. Damn, I was not aware Firestream was nerfed that severely, since I never used it before. Magic Trap can indeed crit, as can Shockwave. Supercharged Glyphs again does not benefit.